# Why is this regex matching only once no matter what I execute it against?

Tags: regex, language-agnostic

I have this regex:

```
/foo|bar\/baz/
```

For some reason, it matches strings that contain multiple occurences of `foo` and `bar/baz` only once (e.g `foo the bar/baz`). Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matches everything only once because you didn't enable **global search** - a feature that prevents regex engines from returning at the first match. You can enable it with the `g` flag, like this:

```
/foo|bar\/baz/g
```

The above regex will match `foo the bar/baz` twice, as one would expect in the first place.